# Does angular have a similar concept to ruby's module mixins?

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to have a base factory (or service) from which other services share methods.

Is this possible in angular and if so, how?

Comment: Angular is a framework, Ruby is a language.  You can probably implement something like what you are interested in using JavaScript (the primary language Angular is developed in), But here you are trying to compare Oranges to Apple Pie.

Comment: I think this is a pretty reasonable question to ask. AngularJS leads to people trying to do fairly sophisticated applications and mixins would be useful for many things. Javascript does allow you to implement such patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/guObDjeLUYCEsp4omusX?p=preview

Read this:

https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/

Factories and Services are just functions, so the same patterns in vanilla javascript are equally applicable.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, foobar) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.fb = new foobar();
});

app.factory('foo', function() {
  var Foo = function() {};
  Foo.prototype = {
    doFoo: function(x) {
      return x + 3;
    }
  }
  return Foo;
});

app.factory('bar', function() {
  var Bar = function() {};
  Bar.prototype = {
    doBar: function(y) {
      return y * 2;
    }
  }
  return Bar;
});

app.factory('foobar', function(foo, bar) {
  var FooBar = function() {};
  angular.extend(FooBar.prototype, foo.prototype);
  angular.extend(FooBar.prototype, bar.prototype);

  // Anything else you want to do
  // ...

  return FooBar;
});
```

And a template:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <p>Foo {{fb.doFoo(1)}}</p>
    <p>Bar {{fb.doBar(4)}}</p>
  </body>
```